# Table overflows parent on small device widths

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having trouble having a table fit into it's parent element. It has to columns that are set to a width of 30 % (left) and 70 % (right) width. From a certain device width upwards it works perfectly fine, but on small devices (e.g. my Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini), the table overflows to the right side, so that half of the right columns content is not readable.

Here's the link: http://fachschaft-intermedia.de/programme/
I wasn't able to reproduce the error with jsfiddle (therefore I can only link to the original site), so it seems that the problem ist caused by either the CSS of the Wordpress theme or my custom CSS conflicting with it. I have tried setting the width as max-width or entirely removing the width-property from the my custom CSS, but it didn't do anything.

Any idea on what is causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
table th, table td { 
    max-width: 1px; 
}
```

Comment: Wow, this worked, thanks!
Uhm, could you explain to me why this worked? °ω° Doesn't that tell the browser to limit the width of the table cells to 1Px?

Comment: I don't really know :). Was just playing around with some styling and suddenly it worked :)